# Asp.net Mvc Jquery Ajax Date Format

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, format

How To Convert dd-mm-yyyy ?

My Ajax Code

[image]

My Controller Code

[image]

Output

```
/Date(1608411600000)/
```

Comment: Try not to put codes in images. Post them directly into the question description.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code in your javascript code block:

```
new Date(parseInt(data.Result[item].Date)).toDateString()
```

Comment: `new Date(parseInt(data.Result[item].Date)).toDateString()` output Invalid Date                  
My Model `public DateTime HomeworkDate { get; set; }`

Comment: then can you convert data.Result[item].Date so that you can get 1608411600000 in frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
new Date(parseInt(data.Result[item].Date.substr(6)))
```